# Office.Interop.Word.Document.Open throwing COMException

Tags: c#, hyperlink, ms-word, office-interop

I've searched, but haven't found any solution applicable to my situation. Below is a screencap of my code and the error I'm getting. I've tried running as an admin as recommended in another post.

The eventual goal is to use C# to programmatically go through documents in a directory and replace hyperlink addresses.

The error is for the line:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = applicationObject.Documents.Open(FileName: file);
```

..And reads:

> An unhandled exception of the type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occured in ConsoleApplication1.exe

[image]

Comment: "The file appears to be corrupted" leaves very little to the imagination.  Try another one.  And use try/catch, lots of reasons why opening a document isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably trying to open a file that is not a Word document by mistake, it might even be a hidden file such as Thumbs.db.

Filter out any non-Word filetypes:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    // GET FILE EXTENSION
    var extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file);

    // IF THE FILE TYPE IS NOT A WORD FILE, SKIP THIS ITERATION
    if (extension.ToLower() != ".docx" && extension.ToLower() != ".doc")
        continue;

    // Rest of your logic here
}
```

Comment: I'm able to get to the document now, but I'm getting the same COMException when I try to display the address now. Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by display the address. Can you show the relevant code in your question and indicate what error you get and where?

Comment: Just the commented portion.

Comment: You won't be getting the same error. For example in your screenshot you can see it says "Additional information: The file appears to be corrupted" which is the real error. You need to view the detail of this new error to see what it really is. I suspect that links is null or a specific index of it is.

Answer (score 0):

it's nicer to filter like this:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.doc", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this in my VB project.
This is a hidden file that is created when opening word/excel document.
But this corrupted file will be gone once the document is closed properly; otherwise, it will remain and prompt this error message.

Just need to delete this hidden file before rerunning the program.

This is my first time posting an answer and also I'm new to SO.
Hope that this will help. :)